# Is it possible to recover data from a bricked smartphone?

Tags: linux, android, exploit, mobile, storage

I have a smartphone that got bricked last year without warning, and it was deemed unrepairable by multiple repair centers. I did have personal stuff on it.

If I recycle this phone, can someone down the line read stuff off of the device storage / ROM? Is there any technique like harvesting the Flash storage off the MB or offline USB commands?

Device specs:
CPU: Snapdragon 430
RAM: 3GB
Internal storage: 32GB

Comment: What android version it was running?

Comment: @defalt Android Nougat 7.0. Hardware Encryption was not enabled as I never thought I might need it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Flash memory chips can be removed and read, even though the phone does not boot.

If the storage is encrypted, they will obviously only read the ciphertext, not the cleartext.

It may possible provide access through a USB debugging environment as well.